# App Widget update only when visible

Tags: android, android-widget

I know that a lot of people already asked this question,
but I need to develop a widget that sync only when it is visible to the user.
What is my best option ?
Now, I am using alarmservice but it gives me only an option to schedule a sync.

Comment: By "widget", do you mean [app widget](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html)? If so, you have no way of knowing whether or not your app widget is visible.

Comment: Yeah, I edited the title. Is there any option to know if the user is at the home screen at least ??

Comment: I work for a team that handles a widget specifically. i cant give the code out for the company, but our widget updates every 15 minutes or if the user clicks the widget and goes into the app because that will make a call to the server to update the information in the app which in return updates the widget. you cant know when the user is LOOKING at your widget... only if they tap it, or remove it, or add it, or resize it.. hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to develop [an app widget] that sync only when it is visible to the user

That is not possible, sorry. You have no way to know whether it is visible, as that is determined by the home screen, and the home screen does not have to tell anyone the visibility status of its app widgets.

> What is my best option ?

Update the app widget when the data changes, or on a user-specified interval if "when the data changes" is too frequent.

> Is there any option to know if the user is at the home screen at least ?

Only if there are some privacy and security bugs still floating around. Apps should not know what other app(s) are in the foreground.

Comment: Got it.. What exactly do you mean - "update the app widget when the data changes" ? If I have for example stock widget. If I will update the widget data every some seconds, it will drain the battery. Or I am wrong?

Comment: @Kram: "If I will update the widget data every some seconds, it will drain the battery" -- the battery drain will be from contacting the server and getting updated stock prices. Updating the app widget with that new data is cheap by comparison. Either have your server push down stock quotes when they change (e.g., via FCM) or have a user-configured polling period for getting fresh stock quotes from your server. In either case, worry about the communications with the server, which is where the power drain lies. Then, update the app widget if the data changes.